# What is wrong (#1064) with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with this MySQL query

```
SELECT count(items.id) AS numrows 
FROM items, subcategories 
WHERE items.`base_school` = 'UNN' 
    AND items.subcategory = subcategories.id 
    AND subcategories.parent_category = 3 
JOIN `item_images` 
    ON items.id=`item_images`.`item_id`
```

It keeps throwing up this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN `item_images` ON items.id=`item_images`.`item_id`' at line
>   1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `WHERE` clause in the wrong location, try this:

```
SELECT count(items.id) AS numrows 
FROM items
INNER JOIN subcategories 
    ON items.subcategory = subcategories.id 
INNER JOIN item_images 
    ON items.id=item_images.item_id
WHERE items.base_school = 'UNN' 
    AND subcategories.parent_category = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! It now works. I noticed a new problem. The `item_images` table contains six images for the single item in my `items` table. When i execute this query it returns a count of six(6) instead of one(1). I guess this is because of the six images associated with the single item. How do i solve this problem? I know of DISTINCT but i have a feeling it might not be the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @FavouriteChigozieOnwuemene without seeing the full table structures and data, it will be guesswork but you can try a sub-query on the `item_images` table.  If you want, create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data and I can take a look

Comment: You can try something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11aa4/6) there is no data in the tables, so it returns zero, but this selects the id of the `max(time)`

Comment: i just added data to the tables

Comment: @FavouriteChigozieOnwuemene what is the new URL?

Comment: Would using DISTINCT not be better?

Comment: @FavouriteChigozieOnwuemene if the value in the other columns are unique then `distinct` won't help because the row is distinct

Comment: @FavouriteChigozieOnwuemene do you even need to `JOIN` on the `item_images` table?  It doesn't do anything for you in this query since you do not even use the table in the final result. See this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/389a8/7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18081/discussion-between-favourite-chigozie-onwuemene-and-bluefeet)